# A simple query on index of positive real numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $a$ and $b$ are any two non-negative real numbers, then I just want to know the validity of the statement  $\bf a<b\implies a^p<b^p$ in terms of real positive values of $p.$

Comment: Even $(b/a)^p>1$  implies the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, for $a,b,p>0$,

$a<b\Leftrightarrow \log a<\log b\Leftrightarrow p\log a < p\log b\Leftrightarrow \log a^p < \log b^p\Leftrightarrow a^p < b^p$

since $\log$ is a strictly increasing function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use calculus to show that the derivative of $a^p$  w.r.t to $a$ is $pa^{p-1}$, which is positive for all positive $p$, hence, the proposition is true.